# Sql in postgres: select every row in one table that is related to other and other

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Hi i'm new at **postgresql**.

i have this database:

[image: DataBase]

Actually, I have a table "borda" that relates to the table "gateway" this table "gateway" relates to the table "equipamento" and this table relates to the table "sensor".

The question is: I have the "borda_id" from Borda table. Now i want every sensor_id relationed to this "borda_id".

How should I write the sql?

Thanks..

Comment: Given the quality of the picture, I think "unclear" is a very apt description of this question.

Comment: Did you try to click on picture (it will expand)? @GordonLinoff

Comment: In fact, I did.  It is magnified to almost 100 times my screen size (okay, about 7x vertically and 9x horizontally).  Either too big or too small.  Really, a question should be primary text and readable to someone who is just glancing at it.  Embedded graphics should be for further illustration, not for the central concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Publicacao Table is the easiest way to associate the Sensor table with the Borda table. The image describes that Publicacao should exist with both a sensor and a borda associated.

You can capture all the rows that exists in both tables (Publicacao and Sensor) with INNER JOIN:

```
 SELECT Sensor.nome
    ,Sensor.descricao
    ,Sensor.modelo
    ,Sensor.precisao
    ,Sensor.valorMin
    ,Sensor.valorMax
    ,Sensor.fabricante_id
    ,Sensor.tipoSensor_id
    ,Sensor.equipamento_id
FROM Sensor
INNER JOIN Publicacao ON Sensor_id = Publicacao.sensor_id
```

Now you have all the Sensors that is associated with a Publicacao.

In order to achieve what you want, we need to filter the result to get "All the Sensors that is associated with a Publicacao that has a borda_id equals X"

```
SELECT Sensor.nome
    ,Sensor.descricao
    ,Sensor.modelo
    ,Sensor.precisao
    ,Sensor.valorMin
    ,Sensor.valorMax
    ,Sensor.fabricante_id
    ,Sensor.tipoSensor_id
    ,Sensor.equipamento_id
FROM Sensor
INNER JOIN Publicacao ON Sensor_id = Publicacao.sensor_id
WHERE Publicacao.borda_id = X
```

X being the borda_id that you want to reference in Borda table

Comment: YES!! Thanks very much! I just changed the last "sensor_id" to "borda_id" and it worked very well.